# Outlook 2007 not receiving any data

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm having an issue with two of my users issues and their 2007 outlook.

I had a problem with database trusts with their user accounts at one point and got them back online, but had lost their domain desktop environments. After recreating their user accounts and migrating their data back over to their new domain accounts, i reloaded their outlook accounts from their outlook .pst, but now they are no longer receiving calendar items that they are sending to each other but this is only on their domain account.

When I login to their machine locally, their outlook is working normally.

No matter what I seem to do with their outlook, it will not work properly.

**These are not exchange accounts**

Comment: So the local account is allowing Outlook to work but if the domain account is used Outlook does not function?

Comment: When I login to the local account, their accounts function properly. All calendar events are received and basic email functions as it should. But when I login to their domain profile, it does not. This happens no matter what network I'm on, so I'm assuming it this has something to do with their windows profiles....or something that happened when I lost their desktop environments.